# a word to express a feeling that is less than excited

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I want to say this sentence "[an emotion] for the opportunity to learn more about..."

the emotion I'm looking for is something less than excited. It's something I'm very interested in and happy about, it makes my eyes wide but doesn't make me jump for joy?

Sorry if I don't explain it well. I don't know how to say it, hence the question.

edit: the expression I'm aiming for is something that makes me seem nonchalant but still excited about the opportunity

thank you in advance!

Comment: Your own term *interested* seems to bridge the divide well between ambivalence and excitement.

Comment: I'm **curious** to learn more about the eastern Roman Empire's foreign policies in the early 1400's: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_Empire -If interested does not quite fit, curious might.

Comment: I am interested but it's not exactly what I'm going for. I mean, you can't say "I'm so interested for your wedding."

Comment: I guess i'm aiming to seem nonchalant about an exciting thing

Comment: Enthused about the opportunity - Keen?

Comment: I am ***looking forward*** to learning about...    I am ***looking forward*** to your wedding...

Comment: I can go with 'looking forward' and 'keen' seems okay too. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You could try **happy**: "**Happy** for the opportunity to learn about...", or maybe **pleased**

Answer (score 1):

I'm eager for the opportunity to learn...